# Undefined error after webservice .asmx returns successful json data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax

I have an Ajax post to a web-service, that calls to a stored procedure.  Everything works great, accept when I reference the return data, I received Undefined for my variables.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../FileService.asmx/GetActiveList",
            data: "{'dcode':'" + dcode + "', 'actcust':'" + actcust + "', 'mcont':'" + mcont + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
           success: function (response) {
               console.debug(response.d)
               
               var vids = response.d;
               var vlist = "";
              $('#player_default').empty();

              vlist += '<ul class="player_list">';
               $.each(vids, function(vids) {
                  
                  vlist += '<li data-bottom-thumb="upload/' + dcode + '/' + vids.fileloc + '" ' +
                       'data-title="' + vids.title + '" ' +
                       'data-desc="' + vids.descvid + '" ' +
                      'data-youtube="' + vids.ytid + '" ' +
                      'data-category="' + vids.categories + '"></li>';
                  
              });
```

My dcode variable is working fine, however my vids.xxxx are the ones coming back undefined. Possible for someone to point me in the correct direction..?? Thank you

response.d

```
{"d":[{"ytid":"14sA-SpS7D0","Descvid":"Honda Concept","Thumbnail":null,"Fileloc":"West-Nipissing-Martial-Arts.png","Categories":"action;comedy;adult","title":"Civic Concept","descimg":null,"filename":null,"sortord":null},{"ytid":"14sA-SpS7D0","Descvid":"Honda Concept","Thumbnail":null,"Fileloc":"West-Nipissing-Martial-Arts.png","Categories":"action;comedy;adult","title":"Civic Concept","descimg":null,"filename":null,"sortord":null}]}
```

Comment: In your each loop `vids` is giving position `0`,`1`..etc if you console it .Change it to `function(index,vids) {` where index will have `0,1..` position and `vids` will have actually json array .Also there are typos in your code `vids.categories` should be `vids.Categories` and `vids.fileloc` should be `vids.Fileloc` .

Comment: Is this case sensitive?  can't believe I missed that

Comment: Yes its case sensitive :) .Change that let me if that works .Also you can change name here `function(vid) {` and then get values like -> `vids[vid].Fileloc` and same for other fields.

Comment: @Swati THANK YOU!! this worked, has been driving me banana's for a couple of nights now.  So thankful..

Comment: I am not sure how to set this questioned as answered?

Comment: You can answer your [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and  mark that accepted.

Comment: I do I accept a users answer and have the questioned answered???